# Join multiple taghelpers asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a need to decrease html code written in my views, due to this I would like to create a helper tag that does this for me, but I am not able to generate the code correctly.

I would like some help from the community.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" />
            <span class="help-block">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code above would like to transform into just this:

```
<input asp-for="Name" class="col-md-12" />
```

What I have so far:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "asp-for")]
    public class InputTagHelperExtesions : TagHelper
    {
        public override int Order { get; } = int.MaxValue;

        [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
        public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {

            base.Process(context, output);
            if (!output.PreElement.GetContent().Contains("form-group"))
            {
                output.PreElement.AppendHtml("<div class=\"form-group\">");
                output.PostElement.AppendHtml("</div>");
            }
        }
    }
```

I think I have a way to do this with a simpler code and without having been writing pure html in my helper tag, I looked for several articles and in the microsoft documentation, but I did not find exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: FWIW, I think it's a bad plan to use `input` here. Given that that already is a taghelper, your code will lead to a lot of confusion. It would be better to use something like `formcontrol`, `bootstrapinput`, etc., so it's clear that this is something different.

Comment: Thanks for the response Chris Pratt, yes, it may be a `<my-input asp-for="name">`. This example I've already shown has been changed to a `<my-input asp-for="name">`, but I'd like to take advantage of the features we have in the `<input asp-for="Name">`, in addition to the initial problem of rendering more than one tag, I can not find a way to use `<input asp-for="Name">` within my-input.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You shouldn't abuse taghelpers as code snippets. tag helpers are there to add reusable functionality and not as **tempaltes**. Tag helper should not contain any design or styles, which is effectively what you are doing. When you change from bootstrap to i.e. angular material or so, you would require code change since its hardcoded in your taghelper. You are probably better of with partial views

Comment: Tseng, thank you for the reply. The current project that I am working on will have many screens that will be the reflection of the database (POCO), so I would like a helper like the `@Html.EditorForModel()`, I would only like it to be in a helper tag and not in Html Helper.

I will have over 5,000 entries that reflects the database, I would like to render field-based annotations in my POCO classes.

For this reason I would like some helper tag which I used `<my-form />` and this helper tag would do all the construction of my inputs.

Is there anything already in ASP.NET core for this?

Comment: @Tseng: I totally disagree. That's really the best use for taghelpers: providing a simple tag which expands into a full HTML component. I agree that style should not be a component, but it's not really in this scenario. It's simply HTML elements with various class names. While those class names happen to be geared toward Bootstrap, you could apply whatever style you wanted.

Comment: @Tseng: In fact, it actually makes doing something like switching from Bootstrap to Angular, as you suggest, easier in some respects, because you can simply swap out the code in the helper and nothing else changes. You could actually even externalize your taghelpers in a class library and sub-in an "Angular" namespace instead of a "Bootstrap" namespace, similar to a provider pattern. There's actually a ton of flexibility here.